# Cakeyframeanimation and cabasicanimation timing issue

Tags: timing, cabasicanimation, cakeyframeanimation

I have animated images using cakeyframeanimations and used catextlayer animation in synchronise with the image animation. But the problem is the text animation gets synchronised on 1-2 devices and on other animations gets disturbed

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: CALayer *image1Layer = [CALayer layer];
     image1Layer.frame = layer.frame;
     image1Layer.contentsGravity =  kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
     image1Layer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layer.frame), layer.frame.size.height/2);
     image1Layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([UIImage imageNamed:baseImageFileName].CGImage);;
     [layer addSublayer:image1Layer];

Comment: This is for adding base frame for image animation

Comment: CAKeyframeAnimation *keyframeAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
     keyframeAnimation.values = imageArray;  // array with images
     
     keyframeAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE;
     keyframeAnimation.duration = 2.0;
     
     keyframeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;

 [self performSelector:@selector(playSixthAnimation:) withObject:array afterDelay:2];

Comment: This is for playing image sequence animation using cakeyframeanimation

Comment: //    CABasicAnimation * animationTransform = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
//    animationTransform.fromValue            =  [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 1.0)];
//    animationTransform.toValue =   [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)];
//    animationTransform.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:(0 ):(1.0) :(0.1) :(1)];

Comment: //    [animationTransform setDuration:1];
//    animationTransform.repeatCount= 1;
//    animationTransform.removedOnCompletion=NO;
//    animationTransform.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;
//        animationTransform.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1.5;
//    [textLayer addAnimation:animationTransform forKey:@"whateveerrTransfomr"];

Comment: This is for text animation in synchronisation with image animation.

Comment: I have used perform selector to repeat the text animation with the delay of 2 seconds

Comment: The actual problem is that the text animation timing is correct on one device but differs on others

Comment: Please edit your question to include that code, putting it in a bunch of comments is incredibly hard to read.